# Making a syntax parser (part of a compiler in C++)

Tags: c++, recursion, vector, syntax, compiler-construction

I'm making a compiler, written in C++.

Currently, it takes text from an input file in the same folder, and I can successfully strip out all the strings of contiguous characters, isolate by type of character/keyword/identifier (i.e. it recognizes 'int' and 'bool' as keywords, and it stores the 'word' in a vector of strings while it stores the 'token type' as an int in a vector of ints at the same index).

So I'm currently at the phase where I have all the input stored and categorized, ready to check the syntax.

...I think I have a good grasp of the theory, but all the methods I've come up with to parse the syntax have serious failings. For reference, this is the structure that *should* be able to handle any construction of assignment or declaration statements, starting with a generic Statement:

```
<Statement> -> <Declarative>
<Declarative> -> <Type> <id>

<Statement> -> <Assign>
<Assign> -> <ID> = <Expression>;

<Expression> -> <Expression> + <Term> | <Expression> - <Term> | <Term>

<Term> -> <Term> * <Factor> | <Term> / <Factor> | <Factor>

<Factor> -> ( <Expression> ) | <ID> | <num> 

<ID> -> id
```

**My goal is for the compiler to be able to read each token in sequence, and tell what Expression/Term/Factor/ID it is, in the order it was read.**

I'm still trying to come up with a function to parse the grammar of a given statement. Is there a way to make it 'inline' or '1 token at a time,' or am I stuck? I'm trying to design this before I try to debug something that doesn't work - so I hope the general design of my pseudocode can tell you what I'm doing wrong.

and things in `<angle brackets>` are token types

**Method A: "whole line" - reads 1st token in line, looks ahead to find ';' and manipulate  from there**

- able to grab whole of `<expression>`
- won't be able to individually label tokens in order

```
until reach end of file (while loop)
   determine statement type (if)
   if the <type> and <id> are the same, the immediate next step to be taken is the same
      need to determine length of statement to be parsed (find start and end of current 'line')
      in <type> and <id> cases, it should be 'current' to 'index of next ;' (length of statement should be from <type> or <id> to the next ';')
   if <type>, should be easy - target format is <type> <id>;
      if token pattern matches that, then is valid, and is noted as such in output
   if <id>, more complex, is assignment
      if token 0 is <id>, token 1 (=) and token 'index' (;) should be the same every time
         between 1 and 'index' is the <expression> to evaluate
```

...and I don't know how I can evaluate the `<expression>` portion, given that it will need to be some kind of recursion

**Method B: "save state" - function gets fed some input that states what the previous 'state' of the statement was**

- possible to evaluate token-by-token
- ... but I don't know how I'm going to evaluate an `<expression>` without peeking ahead to check if there's an operator token, which is the *big deal* of the whole exercise

```
until reach end of file (while loop)
   get passed int to represent previous state, determine current token
      if 0, the statement is starting
         if <type>, expect to be a declaration statement
            return 1
         else if <id>, expect assignment statement
            return 3
      if 1, <type> found previously
         if current token is <id>
            return 2
      if 2, <type> <id> found previously
         if current token is ';'
            return 0, statement complete
      if 3, <id> found previously
         if current token '='
            return 4
      if 4, <id> = found previously
         expression needs evaluation, expect rat's nest of code here
```

That's all I have so far.

**Addendum: Method C, which is an idea I had, just now, which seems very messy:**

Adding something like 4 different functions, all of which can call each other:

```
function 1 - to read/determine if it's a declaration or assignment statement
function 2 - to determine if an Expression is addition, subtraction, or a Term
function 3 - to determine if a Term is multiplication, division, or a Factor
function 4 - to determine if a Factor is an expression but in parenthesis, an identifier, or a number
```

This last method seems like it's going to be very vulnerable to huge recursion and memory leaking, but it also seems more easy to isolate problems.

Comment: You last method is called recursive descent and it actually the standard technique for hand written parsers. It's not more prone to memory leaks than any other algorithm, and unless you are intending to write expressions with thousands of terms the recursion isn't a problem either. In fact all parsers are recursive, because the grammar they are parsing is recursive. However your grammer is not suitable for a recursive decent parser because it contains [left recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion). If you remove the left recursion then I think method C is the way to go.

Comment: Here: https://github.com/Armin-Montigny/MCDC you will find a handwritten shift-reduce parser (+ scanner + code generator + virtual machine + abstract syntax tree + symbol table). Maybe it will give you some idea on how you could do.

Comment: @john - thank you - and yes, left-recursion is the point of failure here. The thing I should be effectively checking for would be changing "Expression + Term" to  " + Term Expression" - I don't suppose you know a way to 'peek' ahead in a vector?

Answer (score 1):

As was already pointed out in the comments, your method C is known as recursive descent and is the way to go, but can't handle left recursion. So how to deal with that?

You can rewrite your grammar to remove the left recursion and you'd come up with something like this:

```
<Expression>     -> <Term> <ExpressionTail>
<ExpressionTail> -> + <Term> <ExpressionTail> | - <Term> <ExpressionTail> | ε
```

If you directly translated this into code, you'd end up with something like:

```
Expression* parseExpression() {
    Expression* operand = parseTerm();
    ExpressionTail* tail = parseExpressionTail();
    return new Expression(operand, tail);
}

ExpressionTail* parseExpressionTail() {
    if (current token is '+' or '-') {
        char operator = current token;
        move to next token;
        Expression* operand = parseTerm();
        ExpressionTail* tail = parseExpressionTail();
        return new OperatorExpressionTail(operator, operand, tail);
    } else {
        return new EmptyExpressionTail();
    }
}
```

There's a couple of problems with that though:

First of all the rewritten grammar is decidedly less readable than the original. Of course you could avoid this problem by documenting one version of the grammar and implementing another one, but the structure of the code still contains the same complexity. Having separate `parseFooTail()` methods for every level of left-recursive definitions can sure be annoying and clutter up the code.

The most important caveat, however, is the structure of the tree we're generating: In the above code the generated tree is directly based on the rewritten grammar and will not look like one for the original grammar would. This tree is unwieldy to work with because we can't even directly access the right operands of an operator - we have to iterate over the tail pointers instead. What we'd want is to generate a tree where each infix expression is represented as a node with an operator and two operands just like in the original grammar.

To do that we could replace `return new Expression(operand, tail)` with code that iterates over the tail and constructs a proper expression tree from that. Or we could get rid of the `ExpressionTail` structure altogether and generate that tree directly inside `parseExpressionTail` by passing the left operand along as an argument:

```
Expression* parseExpression() {
    Expression* operand = parseTerm();
    return parseExpressionTail(operand);
}

Expression* parseExpressionTail(Expression* leftOperand) {
    if (current token is '+' or '-') {
        char operator = current token;
        move to next token;
        Expression* rightOperand = parseTerm();
        Expression* newLeftOperand = new InfixExpression(operator, leftOperand, rightOperand);
        return parseExpressionTail(newLeftOperand);
    } else {
        return leftOperand;
    }
}
```

Now this will produce the kind of tree we want, but it's still not particularly nice to read. One thing you might notice is that `parseExpressionTail` is now tail-recursive, which means that it can easily be rewritten as a loop. Once we did that the function will no longer be directly recursive, so it can be inlined into `parseExpression`. So let's do that:

```
Expression* parseExpression() {
    Expression* leftOperand = parseTerm();
    while (current token is '+' or '-') {
        char operator = current token;
        move to next token;
        Expression* rightOperand = parseTerm();
        expression = new InfixExpression(operator, leftOperand, rightOperand);
    }
    return leftOperand;
}
```

If we look back at the grammar, we might notice that `expressionTail` could best be described as "match the pattern `(+ | -) <Term>` zero or more times". So if we introduce a repetition operator (like `*` in regular expressions or `{}` as used in EBNF) into our grammar notation, we can rewrite it as

```
<Expression> -> <Term> ((+ | -) <Term>)*
```

or

```
<Expression> -> <Term> {(+ | -) <Term>}
```

depending on which notation you prefer. Now if you write your grammar using this notation in the first place, you can come up with the above code in a more direct way than by first writing it recursively and then re-writing the tail recursion: You could write your grammar using repetition operators wherever it makes sense and then simply use a `while` loop wherever you see a repetition operator when translating the grammar into code.

Now we've arrived at a perfectly feasible way of parsing infix expressions in a recursive descent parser, but having a separate `parseFoo` method for each level of precedence can still become annoying once you have a lot of levels of precedence and the same goes for having a non-terminal in the grammar for every level of precedence. On the grammar level, we can solve this by simply writing the grammar ambiguously like this:

```
<Expression> -> <Expression> + <Expression>
              | <Expression> - <Expression>
              | <Expression> * <Expression>
              | <Expression> / <Expression>
              | <Factor>
```

You can then disambiguate it by listing each operator's precedence and associativity separately from the grammar. For the parser code we'd want to do the same thing: Have a table containing each operator and its precedence and associativity and then have a single function that can parse all infix expressions by simply going through that table.

The way to accomplish that would be to use recursive descent for everything else, but use a specialized algorithm inside the function that parses infix expressions, such as precedence climbing (see [this blog post by Eli Bendersky](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/08/02/parsing-expressions-by-precedence-climbing) and/or [the explanation on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_parser#Precedence_climbing_method)).